# Fetching data with multiple where condition problem

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to fetch data from a `collection` with two `where` conditions. The problem I am facing is, I need to press **Get Data** button twice. I am unable to understand why.

Here is my function:

```
 async get_data(){
    
    console.log(this.mnth);
    console.log(this.selected_user_authId);
    //where condition
await this.firestore.collection("complaints",ref => ref
.where("complaint_agent_id", "==", this.selected_user_authId)
.where("complaint_date_month", "==", this.mnth)
.orderBy('ticketid', 'desc')
)
    .get()
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log("insidesub")
      if(!response.docs.length){
        console.log("no data available");
        return false;
      }
      this.goalList=[];
      for(let item of response.docs){
             var data = Object.assign(item.data(), {docid : item.id})
             this.goalList.push(data);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.goalList);
  )}
```

My **console.log** screenshot

[image]

My index image, I clicked on link in console.log to create this index

[image]

Where might be the problem?

Comment: how did you log the `goalList` to the console? The code above doesn't include how you logged the result to the console

Comment: forgot to add that line in the end `console.log(this.goalList);` , edited the question

Comment: Can you give it a try changing your method so it's not `async/await`? I believe this should be impacting you as it's waiting for the query to return the data, but it only refreshes once you click again. Besides that, be aware that as indicated in the official [Angularfire repository](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md), this type of chaining of `where` and with `orderBy()` with different fields might not work properly.